# add multiple children to one XML element with PHP

Tags: php, xml, element, children

I think this task is not to hard, but it looks like i can't figure it out...

This is the data I have:

```
        $_SESSION["username"]
        $_SESSION["id"]
```

I want to store these in an XML-file called accounts.xml on registration. This question is not about the entire process, I'm only wondering how to store this correct. After the process I want to have these new structure in my XML-file:

```
       <account>
           <username>  value of $_SESSION["username"]  </username>
           <user_id>  value of $_SESSION["id"]  </user_id>
       </account>
```

This is the code I am using so far:

```
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('accounts.xml');

        $new = new SimpleXMLElement("<account></account>");
        $new->addChild('username', '$_SESSION["username"]');
        $new->addChild('user_id', '$_SESSION["id"]');

        file_put_contents('accounts.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

I tried some variations, but usually I end up with something like this:

```
       <username>  $_SESSION["username"]
          <user_id>  $_SESSION["id"]  </user_id>
       </username>
```

As you can see I have multiple problems:

1.: the < account > element is not even created.
2.: the user_id is inside the username - i don't want that
and 3.: the variables themselves are stored to the file, not their values...

Can you please help me to make things right, here?

**note: it is important, that when running another registration, this code works again, without deleting or overwriting anything, simply adding another structure as posted above**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a typo but you are saving `$xml` to file, not `$new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('accounts.xml');


        $account = $xml->addChild('account');
        $account->addChild('username', $_SESSION["username"]);
        $account->addChild('user_id', $_SESSION["id"]);


        file_put_contents('accounts.xml', $xml->asXML());
```

SOLVED

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest using DOM or XMLWriter to create XML. The Apis are much cleaner and more powerful. In DOM it has 2 parts:

1. Create the node using a `DOMDocument` method like `createElement()`, `createTextNode()`.
2. Add the node to its parent (Document or Element) using `appendChild()`, `insertChild()`, ...

Additionally you can use the properties and methods of the node to change it.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$account = $document
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('account'));
$account
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('username'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode('John Doe'));
$account
  ->appendChild($document->createElement('user_id'))
  ->appendChild($document->createTextNode(42));
$document->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $document->saveXml();
```

XMLWriter:

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openMemory();
$writer->setIndent(true);
$writer->startDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
  $writer->startElement('account');
    $writer->writeElement('username', 'John Doe');
    $writer->writeElement('user-id', 42);
  $writer->endElement();
$writer->endDocument();
echo $writer->outputMemory();
```

You have to keep in mind that anything in an XML document is a node. An element, attributes, cdata sections, etc. SimpleXML is limited and only allows you to access parts of that.

Comment: thanks a lot sir, i'll keep this in mind and implement it as soon as i get back to that!